# Proof of $\sqrt{2^{2^k}} = 2^{2^{k-1}}$?

Tags: proof-writing, exponentiation

It's quite easy to observe that for $k \ge 0$:

$$
\begin{align}
2^{2^k} &= 4, 16, 256, 65536, \dots\\
\sqrt{2^{2^k}} &= 2, 4, 16, 256,\dots
\end{align}
$$

More in general:

$$
\sqrt{2^{2^k}} = 2^{2^{k-1}}
$$

How can I prove this identity?

Comment: $\sqrt x=x^{1/2}$ and $(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$ and $(x^a)/(x^b)=x^{a-b}$ would be useful here.

Comment: Sorry but... $2^{2k} = 1, 4, 16, 64, 256, \dots$. So what I am missing here?

Comment: @Polmonino see DimaMcGreen's answer and my own answer...

Comment: @anorton ok, but $2^{2^k} \ne 2^{2k}$, right?

Comment: @Polmonino oh yes.  But I don't see where that comes into play...

Comment: @anorton the first (upvoted) comment states that $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$.

Comment: Yes.  So, let $x=2$, $a=2^k$, and $b=1/2$ (for the square root).  This may be the difficulty:
$$2^{2^k} \ne \left(2^2\right)^k = 2^{2k}$$

Comment: @anorton thanks, got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\left(2^{2^{k-1}}\right)^2 & = \left(2^{2^{k-1}}\right)\left(2^{2^{k-1}}\right)\tag{1}\\
& = \left(2^{2^{k-1}+2^{k-1}}\right)\tag{2}\\
& = \left(2^{2(2^{k-1})}\right)\tag{3}\\
& = 2^{2^{k}}\tag{4}\\
\end{align}$$

To go from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we apply the rule that $a^ba^c=a^{b+c}$.

Going from $(2)$ to $(3)$, we note that $a+a = 2a$.

Going from $(3)$ to $(4)$, we again apply the rule that $a^ba^c=a^{b+c}$.

Answer (score 9):

$$\sqrt{2^{2^k}} = \left(2^{2^k}\right)^{1/2} = 2^{2^k\cdot \frac{1}{2}} = 2^{2^{k-1}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{2^{2^k}}=\sqrt{2^{2^{k+1-1}}}=\sqrt{2^{2^{(k-1)+1}}}=\sqrt{2^{2\cdot 2^{k-1}}}=\sqrt{(2^{2^{k-1}})^2}=2^{2^{k-1}}$

Answer (score 0):

square the item on the right hand of '=' sign ,you will see that.